# Awk script extracting value based on matching regex

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to write a `awk` script where i am capturing a API response. The response looks like below.

```
id:0tesss status:ACTIVE created:2016-12-06T13:24:50.000Z activated:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z statusChanged:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z lastLogin:2017-06-13T06:32:41.000Z lastUpdated:2017-06-13T06:32:58.000Z passwordChanged:null profile:lastName:tack profile:secondEmail:null profile:mobilePhone:null profile:email:karry.t@john.com profile:login:karry.t@john.com profile:firstName:Karry profile:displayName:Karry tack credentials:recovery_question:{question:Who's a ?}
```

In the above i just want to print `profile:login` value which is below.

```
karry.t@john.com
```

How can i print this. This response can vary for different users. So i have to filter based on `profile.login` and print the next to a csv file. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this command (using `tr` and `awk`):

```
tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F: '/profile:login/{print $NF}'
```

Sample:

```
AMD$ echo "id:0tesss status:ACTIVE created:2016-12-06T13:24:50.000Z activated:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z statusChanged:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z lastLogin:2017-06-13T06:32:41.000Z lastUpdated:2017-06-13T06:32:58.000Z passwordChanged:null profile:lastName:tack profile:secondEmail:null profile:mobilePhone:null profile:email:karry.t@john.com profile:login:karry.t@john.com profile:firstName:Karry profile:displayName:Karry tack credentials:recovery_question:{question:Who's a ?}" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F: '/profile:login/{print $NF}'
karry.t@john.com
```

Or with just `awk`:

```
awk -vRS=' ' '/profile:login/{sub(/.*:/, ""); print}'
```

Sample:

```
AMD$ echo "id:0tesss status:ACTIVE created:2016-12-06T13:24:50.000Z activated:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z statusChanged:2016-12-06T13:26:06.000Z lastLogin:2017-06-13T06:32:41.000Z lastUpdated:2017-06-13T06:32:58.000Z passwordChanged:null profile:lastName:tack profile:secondEmail:null profile:mobilePhone:null profile:email:karry.t@john.com profile:login:karry.t@john.com profile:firstName:Karry profile:displayName:Karry tack credentials:recovery_question:{question:Who's a ?}" | awk -vRS=' ' '/profile:login/{sub(/.*:/, ""); print}'
karry.t@john.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` can extract what you desired in the file.

```
$ awk '{match($0,/profile:login[^\ ]+/);print substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)}' file
karry.t@john.com
```

Brief explanation,

- `match($0,/profile:login[^\ ]+/)`: find the pattern match the regex in the `$0`, and store the start point in `RSTART`, the length in `RLENGTH`
- `substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)}`: print the sub-string that omit the previous unwanted pattern